# How to Layout a Watermark Image that is transparent along with a banner image and content div?

Tags: css, html

[image: watermark]

I have been asked to create a layout that incorporates this watermark.  It must be placed in such a way that the left point is in the left sidebar DIV, the top portion is transparent to the banner image, and the bottom portion is a background image to the content DIV.

I tried absolute positioning in CSS per my jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rUg55/):

```
 <!doctype html>
 <div id="all">
 <div id=leftside>
 </div><!-- leftside -->
 <div id="banner">       
 </div> <!-- banner -->
 <div id="rightside">
 <div id="rightinner">
   <h3>My Account</h3>
   <input type="text" id="Login"/>
   <input name="Go" type="button" id="btnLogin" value="Go"/><br/>
 </div>
 <!-- rightinner -->
 </div><!-- rightside -->
 <div id="nav">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">menu item1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Strategy &amp; Performance</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Documents</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Research &amp; Insights</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div><!-- nav -->
  <div id="content">

  </div><!-- content -->
  <div id="footer">
   <div id="leftfooter">
     &copy; my copyright
   </div><!-- leftfooter -->
   <div id="rightfooter">
     <a href="#">Privacy Notice</a>
   </div><!
  </div>
<!-- footer -->
</div> 
<!-- all -->
```

However, absolute positioning doesn't allow me to properly fit the pieces of the watermark together tightly enough.  [image: intended banner image here]  This is an example slice where the watermark is sliced as part of the header image.

I've attached a mockup of what the completed home page should look like:
[image: mockup]
What would be the most CSS friendly and responsive approach to ensure that the watermark DIV is transparent over the top of the background color and can be seen in the banner, left sidebar and content DIVs?

UPDATE 4/1:  I've modified the CSS [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rUg55/2/) as follows:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
background-color: #003a63;
font-family: Calibri, Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 12pt;
width: 100%
}

html{
width:100%;
}

h3{
color: white;
}
#all {
width: 1024px;
}
#banner {
background-image: url(images/banner.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 367px;
width: 815px;
position: absolute;
left: 232px;
top: 0px;
z-index: 999;
}

#watermarkCont{
background-color: #003a63;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 25;
}

#watermark{
background-image: url(images/ghwatermark.png);
width: 576px;
height: 517px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -200px;
z-index: 25;
}
#content {
background-image: url(../images/bgcontent.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 454px;
width: 827px;
position: absolute;
left: 228px;
top: 412px;
background-color: #FFF;
z-index: 1;
}
#leftside {
height: 895px;
width: 220px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
#rightside {
background-color: light-gray;
height: 957px;
width: 211px;
position: absolute;
left: 1050px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -25;
}
#nav {
background-color: #c7940d;
list-style-type: none;
font: Calibri;
font-size: 12pt;
font-weight: bold;
position: absolute;
left: 231px;
top: 368px;
width: 822px;
height: 42px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
z-index: 999;
}
#nav ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#nav ul li{
display: inline;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFF;
}
#rightinner {
background-color: #003a63;
height: 130px;
width: 220px;
padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}
#footer {
height: 105px;
wiedth: 833px;
position: absolute;
left: 227px;
top: 864px;
width: 825px;
color: #003a63;
background-image: url(images/footerbg.png);
}
#rightfooter {
float: right;
}
#leftfooter {
float: left;
width: 225px;
}
```

This is closer to what I need.  However, I'm not sure how to adjust the z-index values for the elemetns in question to make it look like the mockup.  Can anyone provide some suggested values?  My understanding is that the higher the z-index value, the higher the image is in the "stack".  Is that correct?

Comment: The images in your jsFiddle example don't work. Can you also perhaps include an image mockup of how you want it to look?

Comment: You bet.  I have just attached it.

Comment: so the watermark is in different pieces? why don't you make it into one image. and use fixed positioning.

Comment: so have it one piece, fixed positioned and change the opacity and you might need to change the z-index so it displays above the other thing. i think thats how i would do it

Comment: How do I incorporate the watermark in all 3 divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

Give your body and html a width of 100%.
Make a new Div that would be called something like watermark container and give it a width of 100% with position absolute.
Inside that div, make another called watermark and give it a position absolute, but then you can give it a left:50% and then a negative left-margin to place it in the exact point you want it.

This will ensure that the watermark is always placed in the right spot regardless of the screen size.

Here's the code:

```
body, html {
    width:100%;
}

#watermarkCont {
    width:100%;
    height:100%; //or if you want to just make this a px amount, it might not take 100% height
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
} 

#watermark {
    background-image:url("/*image*/");
    width: /*whatever the image width is*/;
    height: /*whatever the image height is*/;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-200px;
}
```

This approach is usually used for centering absolutely positioned elements.  The negative left margin is usually half of the width of the element, but in this case, you will be pushing to the left more, so make it a bigger negative number if needed.

After you have it placed, give each element the correct z-index and your large watermark should be able to fit in place without having to be cut up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  To confirm, the watermark and watermark container should have higher z-index values than the content and banner DIVs?

Comment: Correct, unless you need to be able to click on something, like the navigation.  Otherwise, it should be fine.  Remember that you need to specific {position: ;} to have z-index as well

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url(/Content/Images/logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 560px;/* height of page */
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-size: 300px 300px; /* width height of Image */
padding: 16px; /* as per need */
```